Why is the internal torque zero?
In an object, the forces that two particles exert on each other are equal and opposite to each other and the resulting torque on the particles are equal and opposite to each other.but we know that there are uncountable particles in a system.
If "internal torque" equals the sum of particle's torques, why does the internal torque become zero?
How particles can cancel each other out to by one? And as a result, why is angular momentum in an object constant?

What you mean by "internal Torque" ?

Please clarify what you mean by "neutralizing" internal torque. Internal torques do not change the angular momentum of the system. That's conservation of angular momentum. "Neutralize" is used for charge and not torque.

The fact that there are "uncountably many" particles in a continuous object does not change the fact that between any two particles of an object in steady state, the torque generated by one on the other will cancel out the torque generated by the other on the one. This is exactly due to Newton's 3rd law for rotation as you describe.
If you are convinced about this sentence of yours: "In an object, the forces that two particles exert on each other are equal and opposite to each other and the resulting torque on the particles are equal and opposite to each other", then just extend this idea to any number of particle pairs.

To realise why this results in a constant angular momentum, just have a look at the angular momentum formula: $$\vec L=I\vec\omega.$$ Here, $\vec\omega$ is angular velocity, and $I$ is moment of inertia. (Quite similar to the formula for linear momentum $p=mv$.)
A total torque of zero on an object results in a total angular acceleration of zero, which means that the angular velocity $\vec\omega$ is constant, which according to this formula shows that the angular momentum $\vec L$ also is constant.

How it can be proved by the formulas that the torque in particle pairs is cancelled?

@Rojan We can know this due to Newton's 3rd law: Two neighbour particles always interact by exerting on each other opposite forces of the same magnitude. Ideally, they are located at the same position from a macro-scale point of view, so they have the same distance to any other point. With respect to such other point, they hence always feel the exact same torques, just with opposite signs (the magnitude of torque is distance-times-force, $\tau=d\cdot F$, so with same distance and force magnitude, the torques are equal). If both particles are rigid constituents of the...

@Rojan ... same object, then that object now experiences two internal torques that are equal in magnitude but pushing opposite ways, so they perfectly cancel out. And now we simply consider the generalisation, that this is the case about any chosen point of rotation and also that this the case for any pair of two particles that the object consists of.

Why are the torques's signs that other points exert on 2 neighbour particles opposite?

@Rojan Torque is $\tau=dF$, where $d$ is the distance to some choice of rotational centre, and $F$ is the force component perpendicular to the direction towards that point. For the two points we have $\tau_1=d_1F_1$ and $\tau_2=d_2F_2$. Since their distances are equal, $d_1=d_2$, we can write $\tau_1=d_2F_1$ and $\tau_2=d_2F_2$. Due to Newton's 3rd law, which tells that $F_1=-F_2$ (assuming that these are the perpendicular force components), we have $\tau_1=d_2(-F_2)=-d_2F_2$ and $\tau_2=d_2F_2$. Hence, $\tau_2=-\tau_1$.

In a rotating object ،when angular momentum is constant,  the object has angular velocity. So why acceleration is zero?

@Rojan Why would you expect the acceleration to be non-zero just because there is velocity? A car driving with constant velocity is not accelerating - so, I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding what you mean?

But what about centripetal acceleration?! Is there something that I didn't understand?

@Rojan Ahh I alright, I misunderstood. What I thought you meant was angular acceleration. Just as how there is no linear acceleration during constant linear velocity, there is no angular acceleration during constant angular velocity. Sure, during angular velocity there is a nonzero centripetal acceleration, but that does not alter the angular velocity (it merely maintains it).

If we have acceleration , the tangential force has a magnitude and the torque shouldn't be zero when angular momentum is constant.

@Rojan That we have acceleration does not necessarily mean that there is a tangential force present. If the acceleration is purely centripetal, so purely perpendicular, then there is a centripetal, perpendicular force present, but no tangential force. Thus, we have turning at constant speed (and so, also constant angular speed and constant angular momentum, so zero net torque).

If you mean action and reaction forces in Newton's Third Law then these forces do not "neutralize" each other because they act on different objects. If object A exerts a force $\vec F$ on object B then Newton's Third Law tells us that object B exerts an equal and opposite force $-\vec F$ on object A. But the two forces in this action/reaction act on different objects - one acts on B and so affects the momentum of B only; the other acts on A and so affects the momentum of A only.
